# Best way to exclude results from a big db query in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 to build a big product inventory and I'm having trouble with the query that will show the products. Here's the example:

I have many products - above 20k to be exact in my DB. Most of them I want to show every day, but about 500-1000 I need to display only on certain days of the week.

Currenly I've reviewed the following methods, each with its drawbacks:

1. Create a table product_availability, where each row will contain product_id, weekday and available (true/false) colums. However with that structure I'd have 7 rows giving info for 1 product and the whole table would containg ~ 140 000 rows which I don't think its a good idea - because most of the products would be available every day anyway and only 500-1000 wouldn't.
2. My second guess was to simply add an 'availability' column to the products table, that will contain JSON string in the format:

   {"mo": "true", "tu": "false", "we": "false", "th": "true", "fr": "false", "sa": "false", "su": "true"}

Then I'd make my query like so:

```
$weekday = date('N');
        switch ($weekday) {
            case '1':
                $builder->where('$availability->mo', 'true');
                break;
            case '2':
                $builder->where('$availability->tu', 'true');
                break;
            case '3':
                $builder->where('$availability->we', 'true');
                break;
            case '4':
                $builder->where('$availability->th', 'true');
                break;
            case '5':
                $builder->where('$availability->fr', 'true');
                break;
            case '6':
                $builder->where('$availability->sa', 'true');
                break;
            case '7':
                $builder->where('$availability->su', 'true');
                break;
        }
```

But the problem IMO for this solution is that it is going to be slow and heavy method also.

3. My third guess is to work backwards, not to check if the product is available today, but to check on which day it isn't. This way I'd get all the products where 'availability' column would be null and for these that it isn to run an if statement and then add them somehow, but I don't know how to structure that either.

So my question is:

What would be the fastest query to get all the products that are available today, keeping in mind that only a very small fraction of them wouldn't be available (how to exclude them, maybe) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your first option is the best solution to go with (albeit with some changes).

I would suggest a table structure for `product_availability` to be something like:

```
| id | product_id | mon | tue | wed | thu | fri | sat | sun |
| 1  |      13403 |   1 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   0 |
```

Then you can query something like:

```
SELECT
  products.*
FROM
  products
LEFT JOIN
  product_availability 
ON
  product_availability.product_id = products.id
WHERE
  # show if no entry here (i.e. always to be shown)
  product_availability.id IS NULL 
  OR
  # only want to show specific days
  product_availability.id IS NOT NULL AND CASE
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 1 THEN `sun` = 1
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 2 THEN `mon` = 1
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 3 THEN `tue` = 1
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 4 THEN `wed` = 1
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 5 THEN `thu` = 1
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 6 THEN `fri` = 1
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 7 THEN `sat` = 1
  END
```

This will show all products. If there is an entry for the product ID in `product_availability` then it will get the current day of week (you can replace this with another method if you would like) and see if the corresponding day has `1` to show it.

> only a very small fraction of them wouldn't be available

In this case the you would only need to add an entry in `product_availability`.

Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2bbf1/3

Hope this helps :)

---

Edit: Some method you could use to convert to eloquent query:

```
  ->leftJoin('product_availability', 'products.id', '=', 'product_availability.product_id')
  ->whereNull('product_availability.id')
  ->orWhere(function ($query) {
    $query
      ->whereRaw('(product_availability.id IS NOT NULL AND CASE
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 1 THEN `sun` = 1
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 2 THEN `mon` = 1
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 3 THEN `tue` = 1
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 4 THEN `wed` = 1
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 5 THEN `thu` = 1
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 6 THEN `fri` = 1
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 7 THEN `sat` = 1
      END)');
  });
```

Or you could just do DB::raw queries

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! The example with the fiddle was really helpful! If I understand correctly, we will insert a record in the product_availability only for products which are not available full time?

Comment: As I'm using a laravel query, is it a bad idea doing it this way:

->leftJoin('product_availability', 'products.id', '=', 'product_availability.product_id')
            ->whereNull('product_availability.id')
            ->orWhere(function($query) use ($weekday) {
                switch ($weekday) {
                    case '1':
                        $query->where('mon', '=', '1');
                        break;

Considering $weekday is (1-7) and I use switch for all the 7 cases?